# Slow down slick before next slide

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I've been looking around for a while now, but can't find a solution.

Basically, in my slick slider, I have text which I would like to animate on slick in and before next slick (after clicking arrows/dotts.

```
mySlick.slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        arrows: true,
        dots: true,
        autoplay: false,
        waitForAnimate: false,
        prevArrow: '<i class="icon-caret-left"></i>',
        nextArrow: '<i class="icon-caret-right"></i>',
    });
```

I have tried

```
mySlick.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

    // Run an animation before next slide comes in.
    mySlick.slickPause();

    setTimeout(function() {

            // add animation class

            mySlick.slickNext();

    }, 2000);
}
```

Is there any way I can set the pause before playing next slide?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you may be binding the event after initializing slick. You'll need to bind your `'beforeChange'` event **before the initialization of slick**. So,

```
// bind your events:
mySlick.on('beforeChange', function() {
  // what to do before change
})

// then initialize slick:
mySlick.slick({
  // slickslider options
})
```

Also, call methods like `slickNext` within the `.slick()` function as a string, like `.slick('slickNext')`

In your case you'll also want to add the animation outside of the SetTimeout for it to display for 2 seconds and then change. So,

```
mySlick.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  mySlick.slick('slickPause');
  // add animation class here

  setTimeout(function() {
    mySlick.slick('slickNext');
  }, 2000);
}
```

[In slick 1.4](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#events), callback methods were deprecated and replaced with events. Again, use them before the initialization of slick.